# References between classes are not preserved when loaded from JSON

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, json.net

I have a `World` object that has some references to a 2D array of `Tiles` and another 2D array of `PathNodes`.  Both `Tile` and `PathNode` are classes that have values and a reference between them. (The 0,0 tile references the 0,0 node and so on).

I'm trying to save the `World` object to JSON while preserving object references.
My problem is that when I later load the world from the JSON, the tile loses the reference to the node and vice versa.

World Class:

```
public class World
{
    public Tile[,] tiles;
    public PathNode[,] pathNodes;

    public World(int width, int height)
    {
        tiles = new Tile[width, height];
        pathNodes = new PathNode[width, height];

        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                tiles[x, y] = new Tile(this, x, y);
                pathNodes[x, y] = new PathNode(x, y);

                tiles[x, y].pathNode = pathNodes[x, y];
                pathNodes[x, y].tile = tiles[x, y];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tile and PathNode classes:

```
public class Tile
{
    private World world;

    private int x;
    public int X { get { return x; } protected set { } }

    private int y;
    public int Y { get { return y; } protected set { } }

    public Tile (World world, int x, int y)
    {
        this.world = world;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    [JsonProperty]
    public PathNode pathNode;
}

public class PathNode
{
    private int x;
    public int X { get { return x; } protected set { } }

    private int y;
    public int Y { get { return y; } protected set { } }

    public PathNode(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    [JsonProperty]
    public Tile tile;
}
```

Saving Script:

```
public class WorldSave
{
    public void SaveWorld(World worldToSave)
    {
        SaveSystem.Init();
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(worldToSave, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto,
            PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects
        });

        File.WriteAllText(SaveSystem.SAVE_FOLDER + "/Save.json", json);
    }

    public World LoadWorld()
    {
        World saveWorld = null;
        if (File.Exists(SaveSystem.SAVE_FOLDER + "/Save.json"))
        {
            string saveString = File.ReadAllText(SaveSystem.SAVE_FOLDER + "/Save.json");
            saveWorld = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<World>(saveString, new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto,
                ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize

            });
            Debug.Log("Save world es: " + saveWorld);
        }
        return saveWorld;
    }
}
```

JSON:

```
{
  "$id": "1",
  "tiles": [
    [
      {
        "$id": "2",
        "pathNode": {
          "$id": "3",
          "tile": {
            "$ref": "2"
          },
          "X": 0,
          "Y": 0
        },
        "X": 0,
        "Y": 0
      }
    ]
  ],
  "pathNodes": [
    [
      {
        "$ref": "3"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

I don't think that it's OK that the tile has all the node properties stored within it instead of having them in the `pathNodes` section. I don't understand why that happens.

I'm using JSON .Net for Unity

Comment: This is what UUIDs are good at. Each one of those things that needs to have a reference to it has a UUID. When those other things save they save the thing by its UUID. When it loads, it looks for the thing with the right UUID.

Comment: @Draco18s Any source of how to implement that in JSON?

Comment: JSON is just JSON. You need to implement the loading part yourself, by having a "read the data into classes" pass (which is probably already done) followed by a "connect all references" pass where you convert from UUIDs to objects. I did something like that [here](https://github.com/Draco18s/IdleArtificer/blob/master/Assets/draco18s/artificer/quests/Quest.cs#L915) and [here](https://github.com/Draco18s/IdleArtificer/blob/master/Assets/draco18s/artificer/quests/Quest.cs#L956). Its not the cleanest code, though.

Comment: @Draco18s but why is a loading problem? I mean, the nodes are getting saved with the tiles and I doubt it should work like that

Comment: Never used the `PreserveReferencesHandling` feature, so I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of the JSON you are seeing when using `PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects` is normal and expected.  The first time the serializer encounters a reference to an object, it serializes that object in full and assigns it a `$id` value which is written into the JSON; all later references to the same object are replaced with a `$ref` which refers back to the original `$id`.  So what is happening here is the serializer is encountering the path nodes by way of the references to them on each tile while it is iterating over the `tiles` array.  When it later iterates over the `pathNodes` array, all of those objects have already been encountered earlier, so there is nothing to serialize except the `$ref` value.  This is all working as intended and is not the cause of the problem here.

The main problem is that your objects lack default (parameterless) constructors.  `PreserveReferencesHandling` does not work well with parameterized constructors because the necessary information to pass to the constructor may not be loaded from the JSON by the time the serializer needs to create the object.  It is a chicken-and-egg problem.  So there needs to be a way for it to create an empty object and then fill in the appropriate information later.

You can fix your classes by doing the following:

1. Add private default constructors for Json.Net to use in your `World`, `Tile` and `PathNode` classes, like this:

   ```
   [JsonConstructor]
   private Tile() { }
   ```
2. In your `Tile` and `PathNode` classes, provide Json.Net with a way to set `X` and `Y`, since the only way to do so now is via the public constructor.  You can do this by marking these properties with `[JsonProperty]` and filling in the code for the `set` methods:

   ```
   private int x;
   [JsonProperty]
   public int X { get { return x; } protected set { x = value; } }
   ```
3. If you want the `world` reference in your `Tile` class to be repopulated when you deserialize, this reference needs to be in the JSON (it currently isn't) and needs to be accessible to Json.Net.  You can fix that by marking the private `world` field with `[JsonProperty]` like this:

   ```
   [JsonProperty]
   private World world;
   ```

With these changes, the references should be restored properly when you deserialize.

Here is a working round-trip demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/zrQsQ9

Comment: One thing that I dont undestand is why the pathnode variables are stored with the tiles and not in the bottom where sais PathNodes

Comment: @Alexxjaz I updated my answer with an explanation. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! I thought the problem was that.